Contact keeps showing up with old name after changing it
On my Oppo phone with Android 13, I created a contact, let's say with first name John and last name Smith.
Now I changed both the first and second name, to let's say Jack Bollocks.
The changes have been saved, and when I open the contact, it shows the new first and last name.
However, when I browse the contacts, it still shows up as John Smith. If I search for "Jack Bollocks" it doesn't find it, and if I search for "John Smith" it finds it.
Even after restarting the phone, still the same.
Is there a workaround for this stupid bug? And where's the proper place to report it? Because on the Google Issue Tracker it says it's only for bugs in the API for developers.
